# Need a command for display a echo "success"

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, ssh

```
diff -q file_1 File_2 || echo "success" && diff -q file_3 File_4 || echo "success"
```

used this command , but this is not proper logic that i needed, have to edit some how.

Here `file_1` `File_2` are different and file_3 File_4 are different , and echo will execute twice, that should execute only once and also if the one of the file file_1 File_2 or if file_3 File_4 are different then also `echo "success"` should execute only once.

Comment: diff -q file_1 File_2 || echo "success" &&  diff -q file_3 File_4 || echo "success"
used this command , but this is not proper logic that i needed, have to edit some how, here  file_1 File_2 are different and  file_3 File_4 are different , and echo will execute twice, that should execute only once , and also if the one of the file file_1 File_2 or if  file_3 File_4 are different then also echo"success" should execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on the short circuit evaluations, use command grouping `{}`:

```
{ diff -q f1 f2 && diff -q f3 f4 ;} && echo 'Matched' || echo 'Different'
```

A subshell `()` would do too:

```
( diff -q f1 f2 && diff -q f3 f4 ) && echo 'Matched' || echo 'Different'
```

If you do not want the `diff`'s output:

```
{ diff -q f1 f2 && diff -q f3 f4 ;} >/dev/null && echo 'Matched' || echo 'Different'

( diff -q f1 f2 && diff -q f3 f4 ) >/dev/null && echo 'Matched' || echo 'Different'
```

You would be much better put this in `if` constructs to make this clearer, this will allow you to identify files easily:

```
if diff -q f1 f2 >/dev/null; then
    if diff -q f3 f4 >/dev/null; then
        echo 'All Matched'
    else
        echo 'f3 and f4 are Different'
    fi
else
    echo 'f1 and f2 Different'
fi
```

Comment: Use `cmp` when comparing files and you don't need to see the differences.

Comment: @Kusalananda Makes sense but i was sticking to what OP wants..